# Is it possible to set up a AWS Transit Gateway with a VPN connection in Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, vpn, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to follow this guide about Transit Gateway VPN Attachments

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/tgw-vpn-attachments.html

But then trying to perform this with cloudformation instead.
Have I missed something or isn't this possible?

Comment: I don't believe that operation is supported yet in CloudFormation.

Comment: I've created a TGW with all the attachments with CloudFormation, but not a VPN connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now possible with CloudFormation as of the update on June 13, 2019

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/ReleaseHistory.html